# How reliable is a Honda GB400 (motorcycle) grey import?

Tags: honda, maintenance, motorcycle

I am considering getting a 1985 Honda GB400TT bike as I simply love the look of them and they seem to be selling at a good price.

I understand these are grey imports (imported 2nd hand from Japan) and was wondering if anyone had had any experience with them and could tell me what to look out for when buying or maintaining one.

I know this is a pretty broad question but any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You'll probably find that a number of parts would be the same on the CB400 as on the GB400TT.  I think though this question would be better off being answered in a specialist forum rather than here

Comment: @Mauro, we could make that happen on Stack Exchange, by supporting [motorcycling.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42696/motorcycles-mopeds-and-scooters?referrer=w4vp1kULjeIffAcp4bmV0w2).

Comment: I bought a GB400TT a few years ago. The engine is bullet proof, and as long as the engine oil is checked/changed regularly you'll have nothing to worry about. Smooth, great handling bike with a 'punchy' engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have owned a GB400 for 9 years now, and it have never given me any trouble. I travel 1400 km a month on mine. It has done 84000 km. Great bike. I only had the timing chain replaced. Remember to grease the swing arm and check oil within a couple of minutes of turning engine off.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a GB400TT about a year ago. Iv'e fitted new h/bar grips, new front brake cable and had the front wheel re-spoked with stainless steel spokes.
The bike is great to ride -handles like a dream, with it's light weight and punchy engine. I will get the rear wheel re-spoked this Winter.
No problems whatsoever with the bike. I always change the oil regularly and warm it up well before fast riding. The bike is well made with a beautiful finish.